# HTML and Javascript (Adding )

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a simple calculator by html and JavaScript, however the result of 2+2 is not 4 but 22, please help me with this problem!
Thanks!

```
<html>
<body>
<input type ="text" id ="x">
<p> + </p>
<input type ="text" id ="y"> 

<script>
function adder(a,b){

var x = document.getElementById("x").value;
var y = document.getElementById("y").value;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  x+y;


}

</script>

<button type = "button" onclick = "adder(x,y)"> calculate </button>

<p id = "demo"> </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Voting down for `Bug`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly adding to ASDFGerte's answer you need to convert the elements x and y to integers because get element by id returns a string to do this you can use the parseint function

```
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("x").value);
var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("y").value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding numbers but strings, which means concatenation.

Convert them to numbers first:

```html
<html>
<body>
<input type ="text" id ="x">
<p> + </p>
<input type ="text" id ="y"> 

<script>
function adder(a,b){
  var x = Number(document.getElementById("x").value);
  var y = Number(document.getElementById("y").value);

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  x+y;
}
</script>
<button type = "button" onclick = "adder(x,y)"> calculate </button>
<p id = "demo"> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Note this does not include error handling in case the input cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: I thought .value already set it to a number. So what does .value mean?

Comment: @YufeiLiu 'HTMLInputElement.value is a DOMString representing the current value of the control. Note: for certain input types the returned value might not match the value the user has entered. For example, if the user enters a non-numeric value into an <input type="number">, the returned value might be an empty string instead.' The note already hints at how to limit the possible inputs. See [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

Comment: Thank you so much!